# ReactJs: How to wait for componentDidMount() to finish before rendering?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

How to wait for async componentDidMount() to finish before rendering?

My app.jsx:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        loggedInUser: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isAuthenticating: true
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    try {
        var user = authUser();
        console.log('User: ' + user)
        if (user) {
            console.log('Is logged in: ' + this.state.loggedInUser)
            this.userHasAuthenticated(true);  
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
       alert(e);
    }
    this.setState({ isAuthenticating: false });
}

render() { 
   console.log('in render: ' + this.state.loggedInUser)
   // Should execute **after** authUser() in componentDidMount has finished  
   ...
}
```

componentDidMount calls this async function:

```
function authUser() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        return user
    })
}
console.log('in render: ' + this.state.loggedInUser)
```

How can I make the render method wait for authUser() in componentDidMount?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't wait for `componentDidMount` to finish before rendering, that would be a misuse of the library, wait for your `authUser` to finish.

You can do that by utilising your `isAuthenticating` state property in combination with `promises`.

```
function authUser() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
         if (user) {
            resolve(user);
         } else {
            reject('User not logged in');
         }             
      });
   });
}
```

You could use your existing `isAuthenticating` flag as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    authUser().then((user) => {
       this.userHasAuthenticated(true);
       this.setState({ isAuthenticating: false });
    }, (error) => {
       this.setState({ isAuthenticating: false });
       alert(e);
    });
}
```

Then inside render:

```
render() {
   if (this.state.isAuthenticating) return null;
   ...
}
```

This will prevent your component from being added to the DOM until your `authUser` function completes.

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick. I should read up on promises :)

Comment: pairs nicely with a Spinner component rendered when loading is true

Comment: Quite neat solution

Answer (score 2):

Your `authUser()` function doesn't seem to be set up correctly. You're returning the user object in the callback, but the function itself is not returning anything so `var user = authUser();` will always return `undefined`.

You'll need to change `authUser()` to either call a callback function or return a `Promise` that resolves when the user is returned from Firebase. Then set the authentication status to your state once the promise is resolved or the callback is executed. In your `render()` function return `null` if the authentication has not yet finished.

Async function with callback:

```
function authUser(callback) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        callback(user);
    })
}
```

Using the callback with your component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    try {
        authUser(function(user) {
            console.log('User: ' + user)
            if (user) {
                console.log('Is logged in: ' + this.state.loggedInUser)
                this.userHasAuthenticated(true);  
                this.setState({ isAuthenticating: false });
            }
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
       alert(e);
    }
}

render() { 
   console.log('in render: ' + this.state.loggedInUser)
   if (this.state.isAuthenticating === true) {
       return null;
   }
   // Rest of component rendering here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` will always fire **after** the first render.

either use `componentWillMount` or live with the second render, `setState` triggers a new render and componentWillMount always fires after the component did mount, i.e it rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the component to not being rendered, wrap your component with some custom authorization component and don't render your component if the user is not logged in.
It's bad practice to try preventing the `render` function to call.

Answer (score -1):

I think here the problem is that `authUser` is async. I would use promises in order to handle in a clean way the async response. I do not know firebase API but apparently support promises: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Otherwise you could use a library like bluebird and modify your authUser function to return a promise: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/working-with-callbacks.html

If your are not familiar with promises, you should first of all read about the fundamentals: https://bitsofco.de/javascript-promises-101/