# Why does my firebase onAuthStateChanged() trigger multiple times? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

My `firebase` method `onAuthStateChanged()` trigger several times when I sign in and out using `firebase-authentication` according to `console.log`. Isn't it supposed to trigger only once at login and once at logout. The result is that when signing out, the navigation to a previous page is triggered several times. Here's the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => this.loginFunc(user));
}

loginFunc(user) {
   if (user) {
     console.log('LOGGED IN');
}else {
  console.log('LOGGED OUT');
  this.props.navigation.navigate('FbLogin');
}
console.log('onAUTH LOGGED IN: ', user);
}
```

This is what the console looks like. As you can see both login and logout are triggered on just a single logout click. On login, it triggers twice....

```
LOGGED OUT
FbLogin.js:46 onAUTH:  null
LoggedIn.js:27 LOGGED OUT
LoggedIn.js:30 onAUTH LOGGED IN:  null
FbLogin.js:44 LOGGED OUT
FbLogin.js:46 onAUTH:  null
```

My logout button looks like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight //LOGOUT
   style={{
      ...
   }}
   onPress={() => {
      fbAuth.signOut();
      this.setState({ loginState: "You are logged out" });
   }}
   >
      <Text>Logout</Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: In your console messages there seem to be two classes writing messages: `FbLogin.js` and `LoggedIn.js`. Or am i reading that wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Yes this is normal, onAuthStateChanged will keep triggering,
I solved this by using this code:

```
  var authFlag = true;
  Firebase.onAuthStateChanged( user => {
    if(authFlag) {
      authFlag = false;
      if (user) {
        // Do something,
      }
      else {
        // Alert.alert("Auth Error")
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why do it keep triggering even we don't make a auth changed? Do you have any doc about it

Comment: found this post here and it worked for me, I also feel that it is more elegant the above answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376453/reactjs-how-to-wait-for-componentdidmount-to-finish-before-rendering

Comment: This answer needs to be down voted. The code doesnt stop it from firing but just avoid the inside lines from calling. What about logout?

Comment: I voted this down because if we don't understand the underlying mechanism and just skip the first time, there'll be scenario we miss running the code below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address this by resolving a promise within the `onAuthStateChanged` listener. In my case, I was only interested in the user's ID token.

```
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
      androidClientId: "XXXXXXX",
      iosClientId: "XXXXXXX",
      expoClientId: "XXXXXXX",
  });

  const promptGoogleLogin = useCallback(() => {
    promptAsync().catch(console.error);
  }, [promptAsync]);

  const loginWithFirebaseIdToken = async (idToken: string) => {
    // Send idToken to the backend to authenticate user and return custom token
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResponse = async (response: AuthSessionResult) => {
        if (response.type === "success") {
            const { authentication } = response;

            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
              authentication.idToken,
              authentication.accessToken
            );

            await signInWithCredential(firebaseAuth, credential);

            const idToken = await getUserIdToken();

            // Send Firebase token to my backend to continue auth flow
            loginWithFirebaseIdToken(idToken);
        }
    }

    if (response) {
        handleResponse(response);
    }
  }, [response]);

  // The secret ingredient
  const getUserIdToken = (): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          user.getIdToken().then(resolve);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to HALF the number of times it runs (from 4 to 2) by simply putting the function into a useEffect and leaving the [] empty.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
         ...DOING SOMETHING...
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

I realize you might not have been using the same functional components when asking this question, but this issue has been driving me crazy, as well. If someone knows the underlying reason why this happens and could bring us down to a single time running the code, that would be awesome.